# Resetting Date Entry box and re-selection all check buttons in tkinter after button is pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, checkbox

I have created multiple check boxes using for loop. Here for simplicity, these are just 5 but actually they are up to 100. Now what I want is when "submit" button is pressed, then along with the execution of the function associated with button, the Date Entry box should again show the initial date i.e system's date and also all the unchecked check boxes should become checked again, I mean everything should become as it was before clicking the button.
I tried to append all the check boxes in a list and mapped a function ***lambda x : x.select()*** on the list but it didn't work.
So, now what can be the best solution for that?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
import tkinter.messagebox as tkm

def submit_attendance():
    tkm.showinfo('Success', 'Attendance is taken.')

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

enterDate_Label = Label(frame, text = 'Select Date : ').pack()
    
Date_Entry = DateEntry(frame, date_pattern = 'dd/mm/yyyy').pack()

note_Label = Label(frame, text = 'Note: Uncheck the boxes for absentees').pack()

text = Text(frame, cursor = 'arrow')
text.pack()

students = [{'Reg': '2018-MC-01', 'Name': 'Hussain Ahmed'},
            {'Reg': '2018-MC-02', 'Name': 'Kamran Akmal'},
            {'Reg': '2018-MC-03', 'Name': 'Virat Kohli'},
            {'Reg': '2018-MC-04', 'Name': 'Abdul Ghani'},
            {'Reg': '2018-MC-05', 'Name': 'Hafiz Faizan Shahid'}]

varis = []
for std in students:
    reg = std['Reg']
    name = std['Name']
    var = StringVar()
    cb = Checkbutton(text, text = f"{reg}\t{name}", variable = var, offvalue = f"{reg}\t{name}")
    cb.select()
    text.window_create('end', window=cb)
    text.insert('end', '\n')
    varis.append(var)

Button(frame, text='Submit'.upper(), command = submit_attendance).pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to call `set` on each of the variables in `varis`.

```
def submit_attendance():
    ...
    for var in varis:
        var.set(1)
```

As for the date entry, you first have to create it and lay it out in two steps, which is generally a best practice anyway:

```
Date_Entry = DateEntry(frame, date_pattern = 'dd/mm/yyyy')
Date_Entry.pack()
```

Then, you can use the [set_date](https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/DateEntry.html#tkcalendar.DateEntry.set_date) method on `Date_Entry` to set it to whatever date/time you want.

```
Date_Entry.set_date(<whatever date you want>)
```

Comment: But the Date Entry is already created. I just wanted it to set back to the default date after the user changes the date and press submit. Do you mean,  the solution is to create and pack the date entry again?

Comment: No, my answer says exactly what to do: call the `set_date` method on the date entry (`Date_entry.set_date(...)`)